# How to integrate two projects in eclipse..?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I am using eclipse , where i have two projects. some of the clsses used in project 1 are to be used in project 2 also. How can i make use of thae classes of other project in eclipse.
Please help me if anyone knows about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Library projects. Take a look at this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

Comment: Hey Thank you so much.. This will help me out..:-)

Comment: Then you ought to have upvoted and even accepted the answer.

Comment: Alas, though, the link is broken. Which shows why we don't like link only answers.  @kabuko, could you expand on your answer?